# Setting up a download button for an Android App at a hosting server

Tags: html

I have a hosting server. I make a folder and upload my Android apk so that people can download my app. My html is implemented as follow. But don't know why, when I click the button, it just goes to the folder location where my app is uploaded and doesn't download the app.
How can I make the html so that once the button is clicked, the apk file is downloaded.
My html is as follow

```
<form>
<input type="button" 
value="Download now!" 
onclick="window.location.href='https://link to the web hosting where apk is uploaded/TrackMe.apk'" />
</form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make an A tag to your .apk instead.

```
<a href="https://link to the web hosting where apk is uploaded/TrackMe.apk'">Download</a>
```

Comment: Sorry I am not clear yet. I implemented the line you mentioned and still does not download. Still accessing the folder location instead of downloading.

Comment: Another problem is Password and Userid are required. For me is I prescribed the Web Hosting so I know id and password. For the person who wants to download the app, doesn't know and he should be able to download without id and password.